# Accessing an object outside of scope

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach, scope

I have an foreach loop that looks like this

```
foreach (Student newSortedStudent in studentWithData)
{
    newSortedStudent.Fees = newSortedStudent.Fees.OrderBy......ToArray();
}
```

but now I need to have access to this newSortedStudent object and manipulate with it more.

if I do something like this

```
foreach (Student newSortedStudent in studentWithData)
{
    newSortedStudent.Fees = newSortedStudent.Fee.OrderBy......ToArray();
}

foreach(Student studentData in **newSortedStudent**)
{
    ....
}
```

I'll get an error newSortedStudent does not exist in the current context.

So how can I access the newSortedStudent outside of that foreach loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `loop` and use outer `loop` object in inner loop as under.

```
foreach (Student newSortedStudent in studentWithData)
{
    foreach(Student studentData in newSortedStudent.Fee.OrderBy......ToArray())
    {
        ....
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that makes sense. I can't believe the number of people who answered that you should replace a single variable on each iteration.

Comment: Can you explain more on this? Btw, I want it done separate meaning 1st foreach loop to sort the array. 2nd foreach loop I am doing it in later time. So i dont know if nested, you mean trying to combine the tasks all at once

Comment: @JRoughan , ur right.

Comment: @user1618180, what is meant is that you must logically use nested loop, because when the first foreach terminates the variable inside it will always have the last item in it. and that will not be what ur trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Which `newSortedStudent` do you need to access? You just looped through a collection of them. It falls out of scope for a reason. I'd recommend either:

1) Setting it to a variable that exists in the scope you're trying to use (i.e. define a variable before the foreach loop, and then determine with which `newSortedStudent` to set it with). Or you could store it's index in a variable and use it to find it in `studentWithData`

or

2) Do what you need to do with it inside the loop while you have it in context.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, it's hard to know whether these or some other solution is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a vaiable *before* the loop. Store the newSortedStudent object in that variable *inside* the loop. And then access that variable *after* the loop!

So that would be like

```
Student s = new Student();

foreach (Student newSortedStudent in studentWithData)
{
    newSortedStudent = newSortedStudent.Fee.OrderBy......ToArray();
    s = newSortedStudent;
}

// Use s for your manipulations
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Student newSortedStudent in studentWithData)
{
    foreach(Student studentData in newSortedStudent)
   {
       ....
   }
}
```

Comment: I edit my question can you redit your solution thanks

Comment: are you sure its foreach student again

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    Student sortedStudent = null;

    foreach (Student newSortedStudent in studentWithData)
    {
        sortedStudent = newSortedStudent.Fee.OrderBy......ToArray();
    }

 if(sortedStudent != null){
    foreach(Student studentData in sortedStudent)
    {
        ....
    }
  }
```

Comment: I edit my question can you redit your solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get variable/object outside of scope.
1.One way is use nested loop with some flag.
2.Secondly create Student type object publicly and then assign newStoreStudent to this object,when newStoreStudent got populated with new values.